# Who is featured in the opening of "O is not for Over" in Odd Squad

Tags: casting, odd-squad

Odd squad is a live-action kids show on PBS that features cold openings with agents solving mini-cases. To keep the actors young, they rotated out most of the old cast between seasons.

In the final episode of the first season, the last for characters Olive and Otto, the cold opening features a large cast and crew of a new fictional TV show similar to odd squad but for adults. The camera lingers on many of the cast and crew of the fictional show, including the director.

It gave me the impression that they were showing Odd Squad's own cast and crew. However, I can find no information about this on imdb or the Odd Squad wiki. Are they the cast and crew of Odd Squad itself?